# Check if object created: good style?

Tags: objective-c

I recently did some functions like the following one:

```
-(BOOL)registerSomethingWithParameter:(Parameter*) param
{
    Something* some = nil;

    if ([self checkParameter:param])
    {
        some = [[Something alloc] myInitCallWithParameter:param];
    }
    return (some ? YES : NO);
}
```

There are many discussions about using the `?` in code. What do you think? Is this a proper way to tell the calling function, that everything worked well without returning an object?

I also thought about: isn't it better to check for valid parameter in `myInitCallWithParameter:` within the `Something`-Definition, but mostly these Classes are very small and store only a few values. So everything that could result in *creating* a nil is checked when entering the if.

Comment: Don't really understand why you are creating a Something object?

Comment: A common Cocoa alternative is to add another argument of type `NSError**` that will contains an error if something went wrong. Though, if you look at many of Apple's methods they return a BOOL as well (for example `- (BOOL)setInputGain:(float)gain error:(NSError **)outError`)

Comment: @CW0007007 forgot to mention something like `[self doSomethingWith:some];`

Comment: Are you not going to return `some` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any problem in using ? instead of if/else. I see a lot of programmers using it and I use it myself. Your code style is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
-(BOOL)registerSomethingWithParameter:(Parameter*) param
{
    return [self checkParameter:param];
}
```

I'm assuming `checkParamter` returns a bool. In which case you don't even need this `registerSomethingWithParameter` function as it just creates a local variable that isn't used anywhere anyway ? Unless you've just written this as an example. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While your approach is perfectly viable, a better option might be to simply return the created object itself; like so:

```
-(id)registerSomethingWithParameter:(Parameter*) param
{
  Something* some = nil;

  if ([self checkParameter:param]) {
    some = [[Something alloc] myInitCallWithParameter:param];
    [self registerSomething:some];
  }

  return some;
}
```